# I need to show that if $K$ is of characteristic $0$,the algebra $A$ has a primitive generator.

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a field and $A$ a reduced K-algebra of finite dimension over $K$.

I need to show that if $K$ is of characteristic $0$, $A$ has a primitive generator (i.e. $A=K[x], x \in A$)

I've proved that $A$ is isomorphic to a finite product of extensions of finite degree of $K$ (denote them $L_i$).

Then, the hint given is to find a set of primitive generators $ (x_i)$ for these extension fields $L_i$ over $K$ whose minimal polynomials over $K$ are pairwise distinct and then take $x=(x_2, x_2, \dots x_n)$.

But I don't know how to use it. In particular, I don't see why we can always field generators whose minimal polynomials are pairwise distinct. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $L_i = K(x_i)$, then $L_i=K(x_i+c)$ for any $c \in K$ (and since $char(K)=0$, we have enough $c$'s to choose from) yields another primitive element with another minimal polynomial.

So you can assume $A = L_1 \times \dotsc \times L_n$ with $L_i = K(x_i)$, the $x_i$ having distinct minimal polynomials $f_i \in K[T]$. In particular they are pairwise co-prime, since they are all irreducible.

Choose an element $a = (a_1, \dotsc, a_n) \in A$ and write $a_i = h_i(x_i)$ with some polynomials $h_i \in K[T]$

What we need to show is the following: There is one single polynomial $H \in K[T]$ with $a_i = H(x_i)$ for all $i$ (Then $a = H(x)$ with your choice of $x$). This is equivalent of solving the system of congruences:

$$H \equiv h_i \mod f_i, ~ i = 1, \dotsc, n$$

Hence the Chinese Remainder Theorem completes the proof.

Comment: Thanks. But what is $f_i$?

Comment: I have called the minimal polynomials $f_i$.